# Converting message-driven-channel-adapter xml to annotation

Tags: spring-integration

I'm trying to convert my working spring integration xml configuration to annotation and I was wondering what annotation should be used for message-driven channels or if there was any? Would it be the @JMSListener?

```
<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="jmsIn"
        channel="jmsInChannel"
        destination="request"
        error-channel="errorChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to worry about any annotations there.

The class for `<jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>` is `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` and since it is `message-driven` it is a thing itself.

So, you should just declare it as a `@Bean`, as well as its dependencies.

From other side that may end up a bit complicated if your are going to provide enough customization with `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` and `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` dependencies.

Consider to use [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl) which has been introduced exactly for similar confusing cases: to simplify the way how XML config moves to Java & Annotations config.

You can find there the tests for JMS adapters: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/dsl/test/jms/JmsTests.java

Comment: Does that require JAVA 8 Lamda to use? I am currently only on 6.

Comment: No, it doesn't. You can use it with Java 6 anyway. But right: you have to instantiate all those inline interfaces instead of Java 8 Lambdas.

Comment: Would you say in it's better to just stick with the spring integration annotations / spring xml hybrid approach instead of DSL if you are not on Java 8? Seems like a lot extra code to create to port the XML in that case.

Comment: Well, from big height that's why we have those Messaging Annotation. But from other side it depends of the complexity of your flow: if you think that xml-typing instead of Java method-chain is better, than its your choice. We recommend Java DSL anyway, because of a lot of boilreplate code covered. Plus IDE helps with code complete and java docs.

Comment: @ArtemBilan I'm trying to do what the OP asked about and I'm having an issue configuring the JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint.  I doesn't seem to take the same objects in it's constructor that the xml tag takes.  Any ideas?

Comment: That is fully different story... If you would like to discuss, just raise a new SO question. Although it isn't clear why you don't want to take a look to those classes which are required by the `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` ctor?

Comment: @ArtemBilan It is a fully different story?  I want to do exactly what the OP was doing.

Comment: Please, start a new question with more specific request. You need `AbstractMessageListenerContainer` and `ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener` beans to inject into `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint`. I don't understand where is the problem to map XML attributes to appropriate setters of those objects.